# How do I select the keyboard layout when I log into my Kubuntu 14.04 machine?

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, login, lightdm, keyboard-layout

I have a laptop with a German keyboard in it, so upon installation, I thought I would set that as the default layout of the system.  But most of the time, I use an external keyboard with a dvorak layout.  In Ubuntu, I am used to the login manager remembering what my last keyboard layout was, and using that to login.  On Kubuntu 14.04, this does not seem to be the case.  Did I just not find this option in the settings ?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu).select German as the input source

Comment: Thilanka,the question is not about Unity interface - It is about KDE.